# How do you get WebGL Inspector to show up in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

In Chrome, I have the WebGL Inspector extension installed.  The debug option does not show up in the address bar for the page I'm working on (that I'm using WebGL in). It shows up for other pages on the web.  What are the requirements for getting it to give me the debug option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to debug a local file (`file://`). If so, navigate to `chrome://settings/extensions`, expand the WebGL Inspector item and check "Allow access to file URLs".

Note: (outdated?) "readme.md" says:

> You cannot inspect pages on file:// in WebKit (possible with security settings?)

You can also install a web server on your local PC to dispatch your page from a `http://` url.